# For loop is skipping some stuff! Python

Tags: python, loops, skip

I'm trying to run this code so that it runs a function for all elements of a list.  For illustrative purposes here, basically it should print:

```
'----------Possible Word:', possible_word
```

for all items in my list.  So, if I were to input ['p', 'r', 's'] it would run that print 3 times, one for each of those items.  My code is below - when I run it it only runs for p and s, not r, which is really odd.  Any ideas?

```
def check_matches(input):
print 'Input:', input
for possible_word in input:
    print '----------Possible Word:', possible_word
    valid = True
    for real_word in word_dictionary:
        possible_word_list = list(possible_word)
        real_word_list = list(real_word)
        print possible_word_list
        print real_word_list
        number_of_characters_to_check = len(possible_word_list)
        for x in range(0, number_of_characters_to_check):
            print possible_word_list[x] + real_word_list[x]
            if (possible_word_list[x] != real_word_list[x]):
                valid = False
    if (valid == False):
        input.remove(possible_word)
print all_possible
return input
```

Comment: There are other functions in this .py and variable initiations at the top, but I didn't want to post a massive ugly block and thought this was all that was relevant.  If you think I should post the rest, just say.

Comment: so we will assume that the word_dictionary is global list right and defined before ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `input.remove(possible_word)` you're changing the size of the list which you happen to be iterating over, which leads to peculiar results. In general, don't mutate anything that you're iterating over.

More concise example:

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for el in lst:
    print el
    lst.remove(el)

a
c
```

Comment: Ah ok - makes sense.  Sorry I missed it.

Comment: Instead of removing invalid items from the list, try making a new list and adding elements that *are* valid.  That should give you the result you want.

Answer (score 3):

Jon Clements is right. You generally don't want to do something like this. However I'll assume you have a specific need for it.

The answer is simple. Change the line

```
for possible_word in input:
```

to this line

```
for possible_word in input[:]:
```

This will make a copy of the list for you to iterate over. That way when you remove an item it won't effect your loop.

Comment: It would be good if you mentioned that this makes a copy of input, which is why you can do it this way. :-)